# Vue 2 router history-mode returing 404 error

Tags: vue.js, tomcat, http-status-code-404, router, browser-history

I have a vue app with history mode running in tomcat.
When visiting [www.mywebapp.com/faq](http://www.mywebapp.com/faq) or mywebapp.com/other or ../post/99 etc it first seems to be working fine. Refreshing the page seems to be working fine aswell.

However when looking closer in the browser console i see that i got an error message.

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
```

The page is returning a 404 error for a split second before it redirects me and then the page loads.

On very slow internet connections the 404 error is there for a longer time before it loads.

Anyone know what i am missing here? I have added the following code to try to handle it but without success.

My router looks like this:

```
  export const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/',
  routes: [
  {
  name: 'home',
  path: '/',
  component: Home
  },
  ....,
  {
   path: '*',
  component: ErrorLanding,
  name: 'NotFound'
  },
  ],
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
      return {x:0, y: 0}
  }
  });
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   const publicPages = ['/', '/login', '/register', 
       '/help', '/ticket', '/about' ];
   const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
   const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');
    const redirect = to.path;

   if (authRequired && loggedIn === null) {
    if(to.meta.authRequired === false) {
      next();
    }
    else
    next({ name: 'Login', query: { redirect: redirect } });

    } else {
    next();
    }
   });
```

my vue.config.js looks like this:

```
   module.exports = {
   devServer: {
   port: 80,     
   proxy: "http://localhost/*"
   },
   publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
   ? '/'
   : '/'
   }
```

and finally, i have a web.xml file in dist/ROOT/WEB-INF/ with the following code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
   version="3.0" 
   metadata-complete="true">
  <display-name>my app</display-name>
  <description>
     this is my app description
  </description>
  <error-page>  
   <error-code>404</error-code>  
   <location>/</location>  
  </error-page>  
</web-app>
```

**update**

When i add this line of code to server.xml

```
   <Valve 
   className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
```

and create a rewrite.config file that i add to Catalina/localhost/
with this info:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
   RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```

It is working, and i dont get any error message any more.
But now i have a new issue. My arrays that are being populated via Vuex are returning infinite loops. How can this be?

**Update**

I have tried to add this to the rewrite.config file:

```
RewriteRule ^/api1/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/api2/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/api3/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/api4/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/api5/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/api6/ - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```

**update** **SOLVED**
Below had to be added to the rewrite.config file.

```
 RewriteRule ^/myapi1/.* - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/myapi2/.* - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/myapi3/.* - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/myapi4/.* - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/myapi5/.* - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/host-manager/.* - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/manager/.* - [L,NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```

Big thanks to @Michal Levy for help!!

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#apache

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks but none of those server configurations works for me since i use tomcat and not apache.

Comment: Sorry, dont know much about Java - thought TomCat runs behind Apache...

Comment: https://medium.com/@nithin.biliya/deploying-angular-application-on-tomcat-server-fixing-deep-linking-issue-577565fe303d - it is for Angular but that doesn't matter as the problem is same...

Comment: Hi @MichalLevý ,
When following the instructions to fix the deep linking issue in that link it works.
I can now access the direct link without getting any error message in console, but now i get an infinite loop on my arrays that is being populated via vuex instead.

Any ideas how this is come?

Comment: Vuex is populated from API call I guess? Is the API on the same server? At which path ?

Comment: i have 6 apis  like this /ap1/  , /api2/ , /api3/ etc..
The client application is hosted on /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is result of using history mode of Vue Router and is very well described in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

> When using history mode, the URL will look "normal," e.g. http://oursite.com/user/id. Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their browser. To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in.

There are also lot of examples how to do it for lot of servers - not for Tomcat tho...

To configure "SPA fallback" (common name for this) in Tomcat you must:

1. Configure the RewriteValve in `server.xml`

Edit the `~/conf/server.xml` to add the below Valve inside the Host section as below:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Host>
```

2. Write the rewrite rule in `rewrite.config`

Create directory structure — `~/conf/Catalina/localhost/` and create the `rewrite.config` file inside it with the below content:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@nithin.biliya/deploying-angular-application-on-tomcat-server-fixing-deep-linking-issue-577565fe303d)

**Note:** Beware that above rewrite rule causes your server to return `index.html` for any request that does not match "regular file" (see [Rewrite Valve Docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html)). So **if** your server also serves some kind of API (REST for example), you need to modify rewrite rules to not to rewrite requests to API.

For example if your API is served on `/api/...`, your rewrite rules should look like this:

```
# match any URL starting with `/api/`, do not rewrite and don't process other rules...
RewriteRule ^/api/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```

Comment: Hi @Michal,
I have 6 different API's, how would those Rewrite rules look then?
Just add 6 rows of RewriteRule ^/api/ - [L]  ?? didnt work

Comment: Use 6 different rewrite rules or change the regex to match your use-case. Also note that rules are by default case sensitive, to make it case insensitive use `[L,NC]` instead of `[L]`. Do not forget to restart your server when you are changing the config!

Comment: I have added 6 different rewrite rules in the rewrite.config with L,NC on all. however it is still the same issue after restarting tomcat and even the entire VPS. 

Check updated question, any issues with that format?

Answer (score 0):

@Michal Levys answer is correct, just some small adjustments had to be made for my case.
To solve this issue below had to be added to rewrite.config.

```
  RewriteRule ^/myapi1/.* - [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^/myapi2/.* - [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^/myapi3/.* - [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^/myapi4/.* - [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^/myapi5/.* - [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^/host-manager/.* - [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^/manager/.* - [L,NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```